# Best practice for defining default app settings for custom django module?

Tags: python, django

Is there a defined best practice for defining custom settings that come with a django app.

What I have at the moment is a separate file called `app_settings.py` that looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

# MY_SETTING_1 is required and will brake the application if not defined
try:
    MY_SETTING_1 = str(getattr(settings, 'MY_SETTING_1'))
except AttributeError:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured ('MY_SETTING_1 not defined in settings.py.')


# MY_SETTING_2 is not required and has a default value
MY_SETTING_2 = getattr(settings, 'MY_SETTING_2', ['default_value'])
```

Then I am importing this in my `views.py`, and using it like this:

```
from my_app import app_settings

print (app_settings.MY_SETTING_1)
print (app_settings.MY_SETTING_2)
```

This works ok, but I am not quite happy with the design. I am assuming that I can somehow use the class defined in `apps.py`, but I am not sure how.

Is there a best (or better) practice for this?

Comment: You probably want to use the system check framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/checks/

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://pypi.org/project/typed_app_settings/.

Example:

```py
# my_app/app_settings.py
from typed_app_settings import UndefinedValue, typed_app_settings_dict

@typed_app_settings_dict("MY_APP")
class Settings:
    MY_SETTING_1: str = UndefinedValue()
    MY_SETTING_2: str = "default_value"

settings = Settings()
```

Then in the view you would just use it like this.

```py
from my_app.app_settings import settings

print(app_settings.MY_SETTING_1)
print(app_settings.MY_SETTING_2)
```